# Link errors installing Google Analytics via CocoaPods 0.36.0 using dynamic frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to update my project to use CocoaPods 0.36.0's new `use_frameworks!` option. I am using Objective-C (not Swift) in Xcode 6.2 and the deployment target is 8.1.

Everything is building and linking correctly except for Google Analytics, for which I get linker errors:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NPDAnalytics.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIDictionaryBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NPDAnalytics.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

I have tried changing my old-style

`#import <GoogleAnalytics_iOS_SDK/GAI.h>`

to a module import:

`@import GoogleAnalytics_iOS_SDK;`

But that didn't help anything.

Is GAI just incompatible with CocoaPods' implementation of dynamic frameworks or is there some other trick to getting it to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm stuck on this right now

Comment: Sorry, still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully added this dependency by adding the platform limit with this instruction in the podspec of your private library to limit to iOS devices only :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |m|
    ...
    m.platform = :ios, "7.0"
```